# How to remove space between form buttons?

Tags: css

Here I assigned a width of 25% to each button in a line, but since it seems to be adding spacing between them the buttons won't "fit" and one of them goes to the line below.

```
button {
    width: 25%;
    border: none;
    margin:0;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o3L3ofa2/

Any elegant way to fix this without trying percentages like 22% etc?

Comment: media queries - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934647/resize-buttons-responsively-in-bootstrap. in short, if your viewport is X/Y then the media query can adjust your button.

Comment: remove the white space between them. they're inline elements, so spaces/returns in the code will show up between the elements.

Comment: @MichaelCoker that worked - thank you!